# elixir give error when running the app

Tags: erlang, elixir

I am trying to run an Elixir app and it throws an error.

This is my code:

```
defmodule Learn.Team do
    def start_link do
        spawn_link(__MODULE__, :loop, [%{}])
    end
    def loop(state) do
        receive do
        {:add, name} ->
            player = Learn.Player.find(name)
            new_state = Map.put(state, name, player)
            loop(new_state)

        {:remove, name} ->
            new_state = Map.delete(state, name)
            loop(new_state)
        {:team, pid} ->
            send(pid, {:ok, state})
            loop(state)
        end
    end
end
```

The folder structure is like in this image :

[image: directory tree]

The full error:

> pid = Learn.Team.start_link
>   ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Learn.Team.start_link/0 is undefined (module Learn.Team is not available)
>       Learn.Team.start_link()

Can you help me understand this issue and how to fix it?

Comment: Is that code in `lib/learn.ex` or `test/learn.ex`? It should be in `lib` and there shouldn't be any `.ex` file in `test` as it won't be compiled by mix.

Comment: moved to lib folder but still it gives that error Compiling 1 file (.ex)
warning: function Learn.Player.find/1 is undefined (module Learn.Player is not available)
  lib/team.ex:8

Comment: Where is `Learn.Player` defined? It should also be in a `.ex` file inside `lib/`.